# Windows 8 messed up my Windows 7 user folder permissions

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, permissions, user-accounts

I installed Windows 8 pro today and accessed my Windows 7 user profile folder (C:\Users\xxx) and it showed me an access denied error with a continue button with UAC symbol over it, I hit it and it never finished loading my profile(~150gig), since it took a long time, I booted into 7 to access some files and guess what, C:\User\xxx cannot be accessed from 7 too :'(

This caused Windows 7 to boot me in through a temporary profile, how do I reset my flder permissions, my current permissions.

From 7
[image]
From 8
[image]

This is really really frustrating, what should I do ?

Comment: Do you have anything that's encrypted?

Comment: Nope, nothing is encrypted using Bitlocker

Comment: You could change permissions and give full access to your user (or everyone if security is not a concern)? You may also have to take ownership of the folder with your user.

Comment: @HackToHell - What you tried to do through Windows 8, screwed up the permissions, unless you have a backup of your system there isn't much you can do.

Comment: I am the owner and I have full access to the folder according to that dialog box, I am afraid of taking owndership

Comment: @Ramhound This isn't even _close_ to the point of needing to restore from backup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After fiddling around a lot, I managed to find a way to fix it :).

1. First Remove the unknown SSID's from the folder's security tab, this can be done by right clicking it and selecting properties then permissions, then click edit.
2. Then click Advanced and switched to Owner tab and click Edit.
   [image]
   Select your username(Gowtham) in my case and click apply. It will run for a while.
3. Now go back to the Advanced Security Setting dialog box and select your user name and hit the change permissions. Make sure Replace all child permission* is checked. Click apply.[image]

Now it works.